# Combine multiple blade directives with conditional operators in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I made this custom Laravel blade directive that checks with user role. I want to see if a user is either an admin or owner. 
Is there a way to do something like that -

```
@IsAdmin || @IsOwner
  <h1>Test</h1>
@endIsAdmin @endIsOwner
```

And here's my implementation of Blade directives implementation-

```
    $roles = Rolelabel::get();
    foreach ($roles as $value) {
        Blade::if('Is'.$value->label, function() use($value){
            return (int)auth()->user()->role == (int)$value->id;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [@unless](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#control-structures) help you? Like `@unless ($role == 'value')`

Answer (score 0):

You could make an another custom directive where you could check both type of users and return true if your user is either admin or owner